# ASP.NET MVC, Actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am revisiting MVC after some time I am facing some weird errors, which I just can't seem to solve.

```
@Model List<StockEdgeTest.Models.Department>
@using StockEdgeTest.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Department List";
}

<div style="font-family:'Agency FB'">
    <h2>Department List</h2>

    <ul>
        @foreach (Department dep in @Model)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(dep.DepartmentName, "Index", "Employee", new { DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(dep.DepartmentID) })
            </li> 
        }

    </ul>
</div>
```

This View gives o/p

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[StockEdgeTest.Models.Department] List
Department List
HR
Finance
DB
IT
Management
Corpo
Bank
Facilities
Useless
Directors

I do not know how to remove this line
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[StockEdgeTest.Models.Department] List

More importantly, the actionlink does not seem to working, it just generates https://localhost:44354/?Length=8 instead of https://localhost:44354/Employee/Index

any ideas how to address this?
EDIT:
action

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using StockEdgeTest.Models;

namespace StockEdgeTest.Controllers
{
    public class DepartmentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Department
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            EmployeeContext ecn = new EmployeeContext();
            List<Department> e1 = ecn.Department.ToList();
            return View(e1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see @model in your view. And can you show the action for this view too pls?

Comment: Hi, PFB the action

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using StockEdgeTest.Models;

namespace StockEdgeTest.Controllers
{
    public class DepartmentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Department
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            EmployeeContext ecn = new EmployeeContext();
            List<Department> e1 = ecn.Department.ToList();
            return View(e1);
        }

    }
}

Comment: '@Model List<StockEdgeTest.Models.Department> replace with 
'@model IEnumerable<StockEdgeTest.Models.Department>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix your view :

```
@model List<StockEdgeTest.Models.Department>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Department List";
}

<div style="font-family:'Agency FB'">
    <h2>Department List</h2>

    <ul>
        @foreach (Department dep in @Model)
        {
            <li>
@Html.ActionLink(dep.DepartmentName, "Index", "Employee", new { id = dep.DepartmentID}, null )
            </li> 
        }

    </ul>
</di
```

and in you Index action replace:

```
return View()
```

with

````
[Route("{id?}")]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    .....
List<StockEdgeTest.Models.Department> model= ...your code
return view(model);
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your steps and it is running now, I just need a bit more clarification, Why do I need to use [Route] specifically to expose the actionlink, I remember working on mvc previously and this was not needed.

Comment: It is because Index is usually a default route and doesn't have any input parameters.Since you need to use DepartmentID as your input parameter  for index I put Id as a route value. But  since it has "?" it is an optional route value and at the start Index will be called by default without a route value  and from your link it will be called with value.

Comment: Done the upvote part. So you are right as in the default index does not have an parameter, but the is the index from department controller (and this is the path specified as default path in routeconfig), whereas the index which is called from the actionlink is from Employee controller and needs the parameter DepartmentID(not optional). I tried without the ?id part, and it still worked with just [Route].

Comment: It depends how is your routing configured in startup config file. But Id? is always more safe then id

Comment: I guess that your default route pattern is  -  "{controller=Home} /{action=Index} /{id?}"); Since you have {id?} here already, you don' need to put route attribute again. But I didn' t see your startup file, this was why I added route just in case if it was different.